# Custom Controls in WPF

Tags: wpf, vb.net, custom-controls

Is it feasible to build a custom user control that would need to have two buttons on it, for use in WPF?

I need to provide the user the option of clicking one of two button choices.

The custom control is to get loaded in place of other controls based on app variable.

Specifically I am asking about the functionality or the two buttons on the user control and being able to work with the click events in WPF which I am rather new to.

I can easily read the controls on the control, I just seem to have issues telling if there was a click.

```
    Dim frmBtns As ControlCollection = SplitTopRight.Controls
    Dim cntrl As Windows.Forms.Control

    For Each cntrl In frmBtns
        If cntrl.Name = "btnAuto" Then
            VinDecoderUS.USVehInfo.sTransmission = "AUTO"
        ElseIf cntrl.Name = "btnManual" Then
            VinDecoderUS.USVehInfo.sTransmission = "MANUAL"
        End If
    Next
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATED SAMPLE BELOW:**

1. MainWindow.xaml:

   `<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
       xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
       xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
       Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
   <Grid>
      <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Commands}">
          <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
               <DataTemplate>
                   <Button Margin="4" Content="{Binding Name}" Command="{Binding Command}"></Button>
               </DataTemplate>
           </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
      </ItemsControl>
   </Grid>
   </Window>`

MainWindow.xaml.cs:

```
  public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = new MainViewModel();
    }
}
```

MainViewModel.cs:

```
  public class CommandViewModel
{
    public ICommand Command { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

}
public class MainViewModel
{
    public MainViewModel()
    {
        Commands = new List<CommandViewModel>
        {
            new CommandViewModel()
            {
                Command = new DelegateCommand() {ExecuteDelegate = o => MessageBox.Show("I am command one!!!")},
                Name = "Command one"
            },
             new CommandViewModel()
            {
                Command = new DelegateCommand() {ExecuteDelegate = o => MessageBox.Show("I am command two!!!")},
                Name = "Command two"
            }
        };
    }

    public List<CommandViewModel> Commands { get; set; }
}

public class DelegateCommand:ICommand
{
    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        if (this.CanExecuteDelegate != null)
        {
            return this.CanExecuteDelegate(parameter);
        }
        return true;
    }

    public Func<object,bool> CanExecuteDelegate { get; set; }
    public Action<object> ExecuteDelegate { get; set; }

    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        if (ExecuteDelegate != null)
        {
            ExecuteDelegate(parameter);
        }
    }

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the response, but I would really appreciate a more detailed example. I am new to this technique of trying to present controls on top and  in place of other controls. The Designer is a nightmare and tough to visualize just in code. And your sample is in C#, I can read it and code it a little.

Comment: @htm11h Unforunately, my knowledge of VB does not stand a chance to write a complete example in VB.

Comment: Ok, i will write a sample later

Comment: @htm11h I have rewritten the sample. Feel free to ask additional questions